# How to install Homebrew Portable Ruby when your system version is too old

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on macOS. Once the installation finished, when I typed `help` I got:

```
Already downloaded: /.../Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Error: Checksum mismatch.
Expected: ab81211a2052ccaa6d050741c433b728d0641523d8742eef23a5b450811e5104
  Actual: f80fd4cc877a64b0ac1c105fdc212ca6be08bb034118900f2c2f58edcfe0dafd
 Archive: /.../Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby (and your system version is too old)!
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. What exactly is your macOS version, your Homebrew version, what command/s did you use, and what does `ruby --version` show?

Comment: try, brew uninstall ruby ad then install again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

First, I deleted the brew file that stores in the Library folder when using macOS.

The failure before was due to the connection. When I make sure the connection worked, it worked.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same question, and the solution is simple: remove the `portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz` you downloaded before.

```sh
rm /.../Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

Try running `brew update-reset` in your terminal and then run `brew upgrade` in the same terminal.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me! I was getting some frustrating warnings before running these commands which went away: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/FileUtils.rb:1267: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR

/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.6.3_2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
...

Answer (score 4):

"[Homebrew install fails with Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66800084/1446573)" helped me tremendously.

It would fail to install, because our company firewall was blocking certain downloads, like bottle, during the Homebrew update/install, but it was difficult to determine this because I would get the error above.

After removing the file, try

```
brew upgrade
brew update
```

on your personal Wifi or your phone's hotspot.

Comment: Thank you @travis-m! This really helped (turned off the VPN and boom it worked). Saved my day, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks Travis.M. It worked for me. Here is what I did. Disconnected from the company's VPN. Removed the file (in my case : portable-ruby-2.6.8_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz). Ran brew upgrade and then brew update.

Answer (score 1):

To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above, then run:

```
rm /.../Library/Caches/Homebrew/portableruby-2.6.3.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
```

and try again

Answer (score 1):

my problem was:

```
    Already downloaded: ../Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-2.6.8_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Pouring portable-ruby-2.6.8_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
    Error: Failed to install ruby 2.6.8_1!
    Error: Failed to install Homebrew Portable Ruby (and your system version is too old)!
```

Fixed with opening the system app for terminal and installing Rosetta into the prompt. This happened after system update MacOS to 11.6.7

After resolving this brew did `brew upgrade` finish well.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This solution worked for me after upgrading from intel to M3, while the others suggestions did not.  I hope this trick will allow me to bootstrap into a clean M3 build...

Answer (score 0):

I've been automating this for years. There is a new something(?) in play during the Homebrew install.

I had the same error as above. I filed an [issue report](https://github.com/Homebrew/install/issues/612#issuecomment-1017006938) and got a response that fixed my problem:

```
CI=1 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

I'm not sure what prefixing with `CI=1` does but all my automation issues went away.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Homebrew Portable Ruby tar.gz from your Mac using:

```
rm <the path.tar.gz>
rm -rf <the path.tar.gz>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use both commands, as the second will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: There are already answers proposing to remove the tar.gz in a more specific way. I cannot  see, what your answer adds to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

`brew cleanup` then `brew upgrade`